# How to get parenthetical page links in bibliography entries?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperlink

This is the bibliography from the DiT-3D paper.
Does anyone know how to replicate the individual bibliography items to have hyperlinks referring back to individual pages?

[image]

Comment: See Biblatex's manual or (I think) `backref`. If you want more help, please post a minimal example we can compile with a couple of sample `.bib` entries and explain what you've tried.